# Calling method in MyAppDelegate.m to ViewController

Tags: iphone, ios, delegates, reloaddata, aqgridview

I have GridViewController.

```
@interface GridViewController : UIViewController <AQGridViewDelegate, AQGridViewDataSource, LoginViewControllerDelegate, IconDownloaderDelegate, UIScrollViewDelegate> {

NSArray *objects; //main data model
NSMutableDictionary *imageDownloadsInProgress;

}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet AQGridView *gridView;
```

I need to call reloadData method to my gridview.

When I call `[self.gridView reloadData];` in GridViewController.m (viewDidLoad),

it reloads with no problem.

But I need to call this method in AppDelegate.m

so I import "GridViewController.h" in AppDelegate.m

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "GridViewController.h"
```

and call the method,

```
[gridViewController.gridView reloadData];
```

It's not working.

How can I call this method to GridViewController's gridView from my delegate.m?

Comment: have you tried debugging, whether control goes to data source and delegate methods of table view or not?

Comment: Do you have reference to Current GridView controller in your app delegate. I mean  is `gridViewController` actually the controller which is present at the screen?

Comment: Feels like I need another 'ask a question' about how to debug, or just quit. haha! thanks.

Comment: Adil Soomro. Yeah, It actually display on screen in the runtime. but I didn't make it in storyboards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to post a notification in your AppDelegate that your GridViewController will catch.
In AppDelegate.m in a place there you need to call your grid reload code:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"reloadGrid" object:nil];
```

In your GridViewController's viewDidLoad:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(reloadMyGrid)name:@"reloadGrid" object:nil];
```

In your GridViewController's viewDidUnload:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
```

And your need to add method to your GridViewController:

```
- (void)reloadMyGrid {
     [self.gridView reloadData];
}
```

Comment: That usually do the trick when you need to call some code in Class A from Class B :)